# Pypi package multiple platforms Github Actions

Tags: python, github-actions, pypi

I am in the final stages of publishing my python package to PyPI and am trying to use github actions to execute this process. My setup.py file works as expected but when running the process from github actions I am running into issues when executing for multiple operating systems.

I have defaulted to this process since my python package is dependent off of a shared library, so whichever operating system is specified in the github action a platform specific .so file will be compiled for that platform. So far I am using `ubuntu-latest and macos-latest`.

Here is an example of what my release.yml file looks like:

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }} 
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ ubuntu-latest, macos-latest ] 

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: "3.x"

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: | 
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install setuptools wheel twine
          if [ "$RUNNER_OS" == "macOS" ] ; then
            /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
          fi

      - name: Install Swig
        shell: bash
        run: | 
          if [ "$RUNNER_OS" == "Linux" ] ; then
            sudo apt-get install swig
          elif [ "$RUNNER_OS" == "macOS" ] ; then
            brew install swig
          else
            echo "OS ERROR"
            exit 1 
          fi

      - name: Build and publish
        env:
          TWINE_USERNAME: __token__
          TWINE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PYPI_API_TOKEN }}
        run: | 
          if [ "$RUNNER_OS" == "Linux" ] ; then
            python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel --plat-name=manylinux1_x86_64 build_ext --inplace
            tree
          elif [ "$RUNNER_OS" == "macOS" ] ; then
            python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel build_ext --inplace
          fi
          twine upload --repository pypi dist/*
```

Upon push/PR I of course get this error:

```
File already exists. See https://pypi.org/help/#file-name-reuse for more information.
```

Since whichever `os` from `matrix.os` is ran first is the one uploaded to PyPI.

The goal is to create a wheel for both operating systems and upload both to PyPI allowing for an OSX and Linux wheel for 1 version. When `pip install <pkg-name>` is invoked, it will take care of which wheel is best for the machine it is being installed on.

Is there a way to get around this duplicate upload with versions? Essentially it boils down to there being 2 wheels for the OSX and Linux platforms while only being 1 source tar file being compile. How do I specify the source and wheel for each platform?

Comment: `twine upload --skip-existing dist/*`

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I swapped out my .yml workflow file to use [this](https://github.com/pypa/cibuildwheel/blob/main/examples/github-deploy.yml) one from a tutorial from the cibuildwheel project. Simply copy and pasting will mostly do the trick. This allows for you to specify the OS in the build wheels job and and the publish job rely off of the jobs that take care of wheel compilation and creating a source tar.gz file.